# Chrome & Opera radio box-shadow is square - Any workaround?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, opera

Chrome and opera both have bug in the styling of radio inputs, so that the shadow appears around a square box, rather than the native element.

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome & Opera:

[image: Chrome]

Does anyone know of a workaround for this, rather than just removing shadows for chrome & opera?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/26ts8nao/ for live example

Comment: It is a known bug [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29427](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29427). [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937731/box-shadow-and-border-radius-bug-in-chrome) other similar question

Comment: Yeh already seen that, I was just wondering if someone had some sort of workaround as the bug has been know for a over 4 years and still not fixed

Comment: This may be too late, but just in case...I had a similar issue and this answer worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908195/943746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the radio element in a div, and set that div's overflow to hidden, and border-radius to 100px. Then set the radio input to display block, and no margin.

```
<div class="radio_contain">
    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r1">
</div>



.radio_contain {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
.radio_contain input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me but why are 'overflow: hidden;' and `padding: 0;` needed? Also you might want to add a box-shadow to `.radio_contain`.

Comment: This is to offset yet another ie bug! See http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3253181.htm

Comment: Ah I see, that is for IE 6/7 which is very old though.