# Radio Button with rounded shadow on left in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, radio-button, border, box-shadow

How do I make the radio button shadow to be rounded in Chrome like how it is displayed in IE?  Any help will be appreciated!

**IE:** (*like this*)

[image]

**CHROME:** (*not like this*)

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="radio"><input type="radio"><label>C#</label></div>    
<div class="radio"><input type="radio"><label>Java</label></div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    box-shadow: -4px 0 0 maroon; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**JS FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nikib/b85zpgu5/

Comment: Seems like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140447/chrome-opera-radio-box-shadow-is-square-any-workaround  Maybe you can use pseudo element(:before, :after) to do it

Comment: @twxia. yes I saw that too, but I cannot make it to work. jsfiddle.net/nikib/7sa8v16k.  It looks like Roy's solution worked.  Thanks for the link and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `-webkit-appearance` property of the input element to get `initial` or `inherit`. Then style is according to your need.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  box-shadow: -4px 0 0 maroon; 
  border-radius: 999px;
  -webkit-appearance: inherit;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 999px;
  left:25%;
  top:25%;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:#999999;
}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b85zpgu5/4/)**

Comment: Awesome!  I see it now on both Chrome and IE. Thank you!