# Is it a Chrome issue for inset box-shadow with big border-radius in single side?

Tags: css, google-chrome, box-shadow

Is it a Chrome issue for inset box-shadow with big border-radius in single side?

I wonder know which browser is correct?

in **Chrome**:
[image]

in **Firefox**:
[image]

```html
<div style="
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 20px red;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Box-shadow and border-radius bug in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937731/box-shadow-and-border-radius-bug-in-chrome)

Comment: @madalina-taina No, they are different problems. That issue had be fixed over five years ago.
ref: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/chrome-inset-box-shadow-bug-fixed/

Answer (score 0):

This seems a firefox issue. For this example, I suggest you to adapt the css so you can use border.

```css
div{
border-top-left-radius: 100%;
background-color: #ccc;
width: 160px;
height: 60px;
border:20px solid red;
}
p{
border-top-left-radius: 100%;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 20px red;
background-color: #ccc;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

Update: I check in Safari and Opera too. This is how it looks:

[image] -->Safari

[image]  --> Opera

Comment: Opera is just another Chrome(Blink) browser,
and the style of Safari is so weird...