# Strange box-shadow artefacts on form elements with border-radius in Chromium

Tags: css, forms, chromium

I am trying to customize the styles of some form elements. Among other modifications, they get a `box-shadow` around them. In Chromium/Linux Mint, this leads to a strange artefact at the side of the box. I was not able to find any property governing this or a browser-specific pseudo element/shadow DOM element it is attached to. All I can see is that it disappears If I set `border-radius` to 0, or remove the `box-shadow`, or if I set the blur-radius of the box-shadow to 0. Also, it disappears at the `<output>` element if there is no text content.

This is the intended look in Firefox:

[image]

And this is what I see in Chromium:

[image]

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  
}

input, output {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), -2px -2px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

input[type=range] {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position:relative;
  top:-18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #ffbf00;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #ffbf00;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #2c5aa074;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 22px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  left: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #2c5aa074;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

output {
  width: 3em;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #2c5aa0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="range" id="value" min="-10" max="10" step="1">
<output for="value">0</output>
</form>
```

I found [a question that looked related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937731), but seems to only concern inset shadows, and the proposed workarounds failed. Does anyone have an idea how to work around this?